# "10 lines LESS than the screen height" or "10 lines FEWER than the screen height"

Tags: word-choice, comparatives

When we measure the screen height by number of lines, should we say

> 10 lines *less* than the screen height

or

> 10 lines *fewer* than the screen height

?

The second sentence seems correct for me, but the first reads better.

I'm  specially ask about the usage of "less" and "fewer" in this context, not in a general context.

Comment: According to [Stannis Baratheon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u0wj38qTtFU) use fewer. Or just use the wisdom of the answer in the other question.

Comment: Normally I'm a big supporter of 'fewer' but in this case the line count is being used as the unit in which to express the size of the screen and the size of the box or other control being compared to it, so I feel that 'less' is more appropriate. If the size was expressed in milimetres, inches, or even pixels we'd definitely say 'less'

Comment: @Helmar: The problem is, *this* question is specific.  The other question is somewhat general, and its rambling answers are inconsistent.  Most of them say “if you can count them, use *fewer*”, but at least three high-scoring answers by high-rep users, referring to reputable sources, say “use *less* with measures of time, money, and distance; e.g., ‘less than four miles away’.” (i.e., they support BoldBen’s comment).

Comment: @Scott that is exactly the wisdom I was referring to. It's such a convoluted debate, you really have to dig in a little yourself.

Comment: Well you said "use fewer" and referred to a mess of conflicting answers, so it's hard to tell what you meant. What good does it do to close a narrow question as a duplicate of a broad question with a mess of conflicting answers?